# Image not respecting parents max height

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a container:

```css
.img-container {
  max-height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437">
</div>
```

But the image does not respect the max height of it's parent. How can I achieve this?

I cannot set height to 100% on the image as it will bork the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the object-fit on img:

```
.img-container {
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

**Edit:** **Alternative to object-fit**

```
.img-container {
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


<div class="img-container" style="background-image: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437');"></div>
```

Comment: If you remove the width: 100%, small images won't grow to fit the container.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but you could try this instead then:                                                                                                                     

.img-container {
        max-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    img {
        width: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    }

Answer (score 0):

it is important that the image has a defined height since it will not take paternal heights

```css
.img-container {
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  /*set*/
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437">
</div>
```

Comment: The image is borked?!